# Is there an organism which has a common English name which overlaps with another organism's scientific name (or vice versa?)

Tags: nomenclature

Many organisms have their common names identical to their scientific names. For example, there exist apes of the genus *Gorilla* known commonly as gorillas, and plants of the genus *Delphinium* known as delphiniums.

However, are there any examples of the common name of an organism overlapping with the scientific name of another organism, therefore causing ambiguity when the organism's name is spoken aloud? If written with correct formatting, this should not cause a problem in any case, due to the formatting specifically describing a genus/species.

Comment: For extra points, "boa constrictor" is both the common English name and the scientific genus+species name. Whereas "gorilla" is the genus and also the species, but they're not commonly referred to as "gorilla gorillas" ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One great example I know of is the [duck-billed platypus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus) (*Ornithorhynchus anatinus*),  often simply called a platypus, which shares its name with the [*Platypus* genus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platypus_(weevil)) of ambrosia beetle.

Wikipedia gives a brief history of the taxonomy of the duck-billed platypus:

> The common name "platypus" is the latinisation of the Greek word πλατύπους (*platupous*), "flat-footed", from πλατύς (*platus*), "broad, wide, flat" and πούς (*pous*), "foot". Shaw assigned it as a Linnaean genus name when he initially described it, but the term was quickly discovered to belong already to the wood-boring ambrosia beetle genus *Platypus*. It was independently described as *Ornithorhynchus paradoxus* by Johann Blumenbach in 1800 (from a specimen given to him by Sir Joseph Banks) and following the rules of priority of nomenclature, it was later officially recognised as *Ornithorhynchus anatinus*. The scientific name *Ornithorhynchus anatinus* is derived from ορνιθόρυνχος (*ornithorhynkhos*), which literally means "bird snout" in Greek; and *anatinus*, which means "duck-like" in Latin.

Answer (score 6):

Plants known commonly as geraniums belong to the genus *Pelargonium*.

Similarly, plants known commonly as cranesbills belong to the genus *Geranium*.

Answer (score 2):

["Armadillidium"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armadillidium) is the name of a genus of isopods (woodlice, also called armadillo bug). The armadillo familiar to residents of the southwestern US is a mammal belong to the genus Dasypus.There are related genera going all the way through South America.